# wpf listbox scroll and textbox enter key action

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to build a chatroom for school project and I had 2 problems.

1. I have a list box that contains and shows all the messages, but i cant make it scroll down automatically.(can i do it with `xaml`?)

   ```
   <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Messages, Mode=OneWay}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="494" Margin="255,126,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"   Width="416"/>
   ```
2. I also have a text box to write a message in , and i want to send
   the message when enter is pressed , but the message is always empty.

   ```
    <TextBox Text="{Binding MsgToSend, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
     Height="65" Margin="60,625,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="520" FontSize="20" 
     TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" KeyDown="sendbyenter"/>
   ```

**Code Behind**

```
    private void sendbyenter(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key.Equals(Key.Enter))

           string message = Observable.MsgToSend;
        try
        {
            Observable.mychatroom.sendMessage(Observable.MsgToSend);
            Observable.Messages.Add(Observable.MsgToSend);
            Observable.MsgToSend = "";

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing more code, but I suspect your problems lie with the following:

First, you will need to determine what events should cause your listbox to scroll. Once you have determined those events, subscribe to them and call the `ScrollIntoView` event in your `ListBox` from the code behind. This could probably just be done in the event that handles incoming and outgoing messages. Example.

```
myListBox.ScrollIntoView(Observable.Messages[Observable.Message.Last-1]);
```

I don't know how your `Observable` class is structured so you may need to adjust what you pass in the `ScrollIntoView` event. Your goal is to pass the most recent message added to the collection. Also, you will need to name your `ListBox` in order to access it from the code-behind.

Second, your message is always empty because your `Observable` class is most likely mutable. You add the `MsgToSend` to the collection but then reset its value to empty. When you reset that value you are resetting the value that was added to the collection as well. Pass `message` instead of `Observable.MsgToSend`.

```
private void sendbyenter(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key.Equals(Key.Enter))
       string message = Observable.MsgToSend;
    try
    {
        Observable.mychatroom.sendMessage(message);
        Observable.Messages.Add(message);
        Observable.MsgToSend = "";

    }
}
```